# dplyr grouping and using a conditional from multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like this

```
  transactionId user_id total_in_pennies created_at               X  yearmonth
1        345068       8             9900 2018-09-13    New Customer 2018-09-01
2        346189       8             9900 2018-09-20 Repeat Customer 2018-09-01
3        363500       8             7700 2018-10-11 Repeat Customer 2018-10-01
4        376089       8             7700 2018-10-25 Repeat Customer 2018-10-01
5        198450      11                0 2018-01-18    New Customer 2018-01-01
6        203966      11                0 2018-01-25 Repeat Customer 2018-01-01
```

it has many more rows, but that little snippet can be used.

I am trying to group using dplyr so I can get a final data frame like this

[image]

I use this code

```
df_RFM11 <- data2 %>% group_by(yearmonth) %>% 
  summarise(New_Customers=sum(X=="New Customer"), Repeat_Customers=sum(X=="Repeat Customer"), New_Customers_sales=sum(total_in_pennies & X=="New Customers"), Repeat_Customers_sales=sum(total_in_pennies & X=="Repeat Customers"))
```

and I get this result

```
> head(df_RFM11)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  yearmonth  New_Customers Repeat_Customers New_Customers_sales Repeat_Customers_sales
  <date>             <int>            <int>               <int>                  <int>
1 2018-01-01          4880             2428                   0                      0
2 2018-02-01          2027            12068                   0                      0
3 2018-03-01          1902            15296                   0                      0
4 2018-04-01          1921            13363                   0                      0
5 2018-05-01          2631            18336                   0                      0
6 2018-06-01          2339            14492                   0                      0
```

and I am able to get the first 2 column I need, the count of new customers and repeat customers, but i get 0's when I try to get the sum of "total_in_pennies" for New Customers and repeat customer

Any help on what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to put them in brackets, like below:

```
df_RFM11 <- data2 %>% 
  group_by(yearmonth) %>% 
  summarise(New_Customers=sum(X=="New Customer"),
            Repeat_Customers=sum(X=="Repeat Customer"),
            New_Customers_sales=sum(total_in_pennies[X=="New Customer"]),
            Repeat_Customers_sales=sum(total_in_pennies[X=="Repeat Customer"])
            )
```

Comment: No luck, I use  that code and i still get 0's on the 3rd and 4th column

Comment: @juan-lozano: notice how @arg0naut changed your conditionals... you had a typo: `Customer` vs `Customers`.

Comment: Indeed, try to solve the typo and it should work; I corrected it in the code, so perhaps re-run and let us know.

Comment: You're welcome! Consider accepting the answer if it helped.